# How make getRequestURI and queryString in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am using this:

`<li ${(requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']=='/example') ? "class='active';" : ""}>`

And this code activates my link to me but I've written such code to be active: `${(requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri'] +="?"+ requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.query_string']=='/example/?buy=e') ? "class='active';" : ""}`

But I am getting an error.
Can I get your solution suggestions?

Comment: What error do you get? What more info can you give us?

Comment: example/?buy=e the /example link is active when I press. does not detect the parameter

Comment: I am using this:

 <li ${(requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']=='/example') ? "class='active';" : ""}>

And this code activates my link to me but I've written such code to be active: ${(requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri'] +="?"+ requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.query_string']=='/example/?buy=e') ? "class='active';" : ""}

But I am getting an error.
Can I get your solution suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this below.

```
String uri = request.getScheme() + "://" +
             request.getServerName() + 
             ("http".equals(request.getScheme()) && request.getServerPort() == 80 || "https".equals(request.getScheme()) && request.getServerPort() == 443 ? "" : ":" + request.getServerPort() ) +
             request.getRequestURI() +
            (request.getQueryString() != null ? "?" + request.getQueryString() : "");
```

Note: 
This snippet above will get the full URI, hiding the port if the default one was used, and not adding the "**?**" and the query string if the latter was not provided.